# Not able to read runtime parameters in testng test case in intellij ide

Tags: testng

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class DatesTest {

    private boolean isThreadCompleted = false;

    @Test
    public void currentDate() throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Enter Offer Name : ");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String offerName = reader.readLine();
        System.out.print("Offer Name is : " + offerName);
    }
}
```

When i run the test, it doesn;t print anything. If i remove the reader.readLine() method, then it prints the data.

Please let me know if its possible to read user input from command line while running the test

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It shows me output with your code and Test also passed. Does it throws any exception to you ?

Comment: It runs forever and doesn't print any logs on intellij

Comment: What is your purpose to use Reader? Do you wants to take User input from console?

Comment: Yes i wanna take used input from console at runtime

Comment: You may refer Scanner class for same. Added Solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer Scanner class, to get User inputs:

**Sample Example:**

```
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  

      System.out.print("Enter your name: ");    
      String name = in.next();   
      System.out.println("Name: " + name);  

      System.out.print("Enter your age: ");  
      int i = in.nextInt();  
      System.out.println("Age: " + i);
```

Where 'in' is object of Scanner class, and it can access to read data as according to Datatype.

Comment: I was doining almost same except using bufferedreader instead of scanner. I used scanner as well. Issue was still same